# Cant set List<String> value from <ui:repeat> var status

Tags: java, jsf

in my xhtml i define a inputText variable from which i want to set a specific value to a specific field in my List. Every time i click confirm and debug my code the value is returned as "" (that i set in my init function). I have also tried hardcoding my inputText value to be set to `dashboardFilterDialogBean.dashboardObject.texts[0]` as in the only item in the list i define but still no result. I get 0 exceptions in my console

Xhtml

```
<p:dialog id="dashboardFilterDialog">
    <h:form id="dashboard_filter_dialog_form">
        <ui:repeat value="#{dashboardFilterDialogBean.dashboardObject.texts}" varStatus="loop">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Text" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText value="#{dashboardFilterDialogBean.dashboardObject.texts[loop.index]}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:form id="submit_dashboards_dialog_form">
            <p:commandButton id="confirm_button" actionListener="#{dashboardFilterDialogBean.confirm()}" />
        </h:form>
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

Bean

```
public class DashboardFilterDialogBean {

    private DashboardObject dashboardObject;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        dashboardObject.getTexts().add("");
    }

    public void confirm() {
        for (String txtValue : getDashboardObject().getTexts()) {
            if (!txtValue.equals("")) {
                ...;
            }
        }
    }

    public DashboardObject getDashboardObject() {
        return dashboardObject;
    }

    public void setDashboardObject(DashboardObject dashboardObject) {
        this.dashboardObject = dashboardObject;
    }
}
```

Object

```
public class DashboardObject {

    private List<String>            texts;

    public DashboardObject() {
        texts = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getTexts() {
        return texts;
    }

    public void setTexts(List<String> texts) {
        this.texts = texts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue by adding `<p:ajax event="blur" process="@this" />` into my inputText so it saves the value before i click confirm. So the end code looks like this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{dashboardFilterDialogBean.dashboardObject.texts[loop.index]}" />
    <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this" />
</p:inputText>
```